# Check if kernel and image for dihedral group defined correctly

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism, dihedral-groups

Suppose that $n = dm$ where $d$ and $m$ are positive integers with $m\ge 3$. Consider the dihedral group $D_n = \langle \{\mu, \rho\}\rangle,$ where $|\mu| = 2$, $|\rho| = n$ and $\rho\mu = \mu\rho^{−1}$, and the dihedral group $D_m = \langle \{s, r\}\rangle,$ where $|s| = 2$, $|r| = m$ and $rs = sr^{−1}$.

Define $\psi : D_n \to D_m$ by $\psi(\mu^a\rho^b)=s^ar^b$, for any integers $a,b$

Find kernel and image of $\psi$.

---

I think :

$\ker(\psi)=\{\rho^{2x}\mu^{my}\}$ for $x,y$ integers so that $a=2x,b=my$

${\rm im}(\psi)=\{D_m\}$.

Did I do this correctly?

So, by first isomorphism theorem, have that $D_n/\ker(\psi) \cong {D_m} $. Is there anything else the theorem says here, or is this it?

Comment: Wasn't this asked recently?

Comment: @Shaun it was a different question, it was about showing well-definedness, but I want to practice finding the kernel and image so I posted this to get feedback on kernel and image for this type of function

Answer (score 1):

Your answers make no sense. The following equations at least make sense:

$\operatorname{im}(\psi)=D_m$  and

$\operatorname{ker}(\psi)=\{\rho^{mk}\mid k=0,1,\ldots,d-1\}$.

Indeed,
$$
\mu^a\rho^b\in\operatorname{ker}(\psi)
\Leftrightarrow\psi(\mu^a\rho^b)=e
\Leftrightarrow s^at^b=e
\Leftrightarrow a\equiv0\,(\operatorname{mod}2),b\equiv0\,(\operatorname{mod}m).
$$
Hence $\mu^a\rho^b=\mu^{2l}\rho^{mk}=\rho^{mk}$, where $a=2l$, $b=mk$.

Also, write $D_n=\langle\mu,\rho\rangle$ but not $D_n=\langle\{\mu,\rho\}\rangle$.

Comment: why is kernel just dependent on $\mu$? I thought the kernel must be in terms of the elements $\mu^i \rho^j$

Comment: why does the kernel lie in the subgroup generated by $\rho$? why is it not dependent on $\mu$ also?

Comment: @eddie
I have supplemented my answer and hopefully answered your last question.